# Should you use 'var' or 'let' in the global scope?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have this express application and want to add a global variable at the top

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

// var globalScopeVariable = 123;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // home page
});

app.get('/create/:message', (req, res) => {
  //  add block
});

app.get('/add/:peerPort', (req, res) => {
  // add peer
});
```

Would it be good practice to use 'var' or 'let' in this scenario?

Comment: As per ecmascript-6 "let" is the good practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav)

Answer (score 4):

In your case (Node.js), neither `var` nor `let` make a global scope variable; both will create a module-scope variable (accessible inside this module, but not in other modules). This may be what you want (in which case, `let` is generally preferred these days, and `var` should be consigned to history); but in case it isn't, the only way to make a true global scope variable is by direct assignment:

```
global.globalScopeVariable = 123;
```

Comment: This will also do the same thing **globalScopeVariable = 123**;
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Ammar Yes... unless you are in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). In strict mode, you will get an error. You should always `"use strict"`.

Answer (score 2):

If your variable can be reassigned, then use `let` otherwise use `const`. You don't have to bother about `var` anymore.

You can always consider the following powerful master rules around variable declaration in modern JavaScript.

- Stop using `var` as soon as you can!
- Use `const` whenever you can!
- Use `let` only when you really have to!

Comment: This is *not* true. Global variables defined with let and const do not become properties of the window object, unlike var variables.

Comment: I'm glad someone pointed this FACT out, as it seems much is maligned by opinion or what might be seen in code snippets/examples [or via hand me down knowledge etc] on this subject.  Anyway well done I say, this is actually the only production-level knowledge response to the OPs question here :)